# how to replace an image on an image view when score changes?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have 2 images one gold one green,

When the score is 100 the image must only be the gold image if the score goes below 100 points the image must change to the green image.

```
}

if (score < 100) {
    closeonechange.text = @"Correct!";

} else {
    closeonechange.text = @"Perfect!";
}
```

The green image is called greenOne.png

How is this done?

Comment: you change image of a `UIImageView`.. your code does not have any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two `UIImageView`s you can use their `hidden` property to hide/show them as required:

```
if (score < 100) {
    closeonechange.text = @"Correct!";
    imageView1.hidden = NO;
    imageView2.hidden = YES;

} else {
    closeonechange.text = @"Perfect!";
    imageView1.hidden = YES;
    imageView2.hidden = NO;
}
```

If you have a single `UIImageView`, you can change its image on the fly:

```
if (score < 100) {
    closeonechange.text = @"Correct!";
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"correct"];

} else {
    closeonechange.text = @"Perfect!";
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"perfect"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I use the second example, it was much better!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
UIImage scoreImage;
if (score < 100) {
    closeonechange.text = @"Correct!";
scoreImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowImage"];

} else {
    closeonechange.text = @"Perfect!";
scoreImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenOne"];
}

[scoreImageView setImage:scoreImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

First define a `UIImageView` like this     `UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc];`
and in your method use the code as follows.

```
if (score < 100) {
  closeonechange.text = @"Correct!";
  imageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenOne.png"];
} else {
  closeonechange.text = @"Perfect!";
  imageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldOne.png"];
}
```